# funny prompt with Assembler with converting input ASCII to dec

Tags: input, ascii, nasm, system-calls, prompt

I want to convert ASCII character numbers from input to decimals, but the prompt acts funny. I want to ask the user for the number of digits of the number that is going to be converted and the number itself. The prompt ignores the first request for user input. After messing around with the code a bit I found out that the prompt is always asking for one input variable less than I code it for. Why is that?

So the problems seems to lay within the system calls and not within the function ''string_to_int''

Here is the compiler info:

```
nasm -f elf64 convinput.asm
ld -s -o convinput convinput.o
```

Here is the code:

```
section     .text

global _start

_start:

    mov     eax, 3
    mov     ebx, 2
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ecx, dignum
    int     80h

    mov     eax, 3
    mov     ebx, 2
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ecx, data
    int     80h

    mov     esi, data
    movzx   ecx, byte [dignum]
    xor     ebx,ebx    ; clear ebx

    call    string_to_int
    mov     eax, 1
    int     80h

string_to_int:
    xor     ebx,ebx
    movzx   eax, byte [esi]
    inc     esi
    sub     al,'0'    ; convert from ASCII to number4
    mov     ebx, 10
    mul     ebx
    add     ebx,eax   ; ebx = ebx*10 + eax  
    dec     byte [dignum]
    cmp     byte [dignum], 0
    jne     string_to_int
    mov     eax,ebx
    ret


section .bss

    dignum  resb 1
    data    resb 1000

    ; ESI = pointer to the string to convert
    ; ECX = number of digits in the string (must be > 0)
    ; Output:
    ; EAX = integer valu
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you call `sys_read` with the length set to more than 1. Also, is there any particular reason why you're using 2 (`stderr`) rather than 0 (`stdin`)?

Comment: Hi Micheal, thanks for your answer. 

If I understand you correctly the second call depends on the first? So I've adjust the second call in such a way it doesn't overwrites the first?

I thought I've to specify the length of each input individually, but it sounds like I don't understand this syscall properly.

Comment: oke, so I set ebx to 0 and nothing changed. About the lenght: I'm calling sys_read twice. I'm not asking for two characters at the same time, because I want to store each character in different memory locations. I hope my response makes some sense.

Comment: Well, the way I understand it you want to first read one digit into `dignum`, and then read `dignum` digits into `data`. But you're only reading 1 digit into `data` because you've set the length to 1 when you do the `sys_read` call. You need to either set the length to as many bytes as you want to read, or write a loop where you read one byte per iteration. Note that you shouldn't use the value at `dignum` directly as the length, because the characters `'0'..'9'` are _not_ encoded as `0..9` (in ASCII at least, they'll have the values `0x30..0x39`).

Comment: It would also be helpful to the user if you output some kind of prompt before each read.